# Trap Objective C Crashes

Tags: objective-c, macos, error-handling, crash, crash-reports

How do I trap an Objective C crash (like a bad access or pointer error) so that instead of the application dying with a stack dump, it shows the user a friendlier message and lets them restart the application? That way, I can intercept those and have it email me anonymous errors to a web error log if the end user chose that option on their setup program.

I'm only concerned with OSX Cocoa apps at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A. Global Behavior

You can configure the exception behavior of an application as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Tasks/ControllingAppResponse.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000473-BBCHGJIJ).

Additionally you can set a custom exception handler with [NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler).

B. Local Behavior

Of course you can handle exception locally with `@try`-`@catch`-`@finally`.